# Angular app is blocked with too many notification events

Tags: javascript, angular, signalr

I am using Angular 7 and SignalR on the back end for push notification. In some moment I am getting enormous number of notification and my application is completely blocked.

signalR service component:

```
stateChangeNotifier = new Subject<string>();

hubConnection.on("StateChanged", (state: string) => {
  this.stateChangeNotifier.next(state);  // this fire enormous number of notification which block application
});
```

Another component which is subscribed to event:

```
stateChangeNotifier.subscribe(result => {
     // here is enormous number of notification
});
```

Is there any way how I can handle those notification in separate thread or somehow to gather them and process only the last one in every second or two ?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: read into rxjs, I suppose you are looking for [bufferTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffertime.html) or [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) depending on your needs. But it's difficult to tell without any actual code from your side

Comment: Here is the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, if you want to emit only after a certain period of no events, you should use the `debounceTime` operator

```
private stateChange = new Subject<string>();

stateChangeNotifier = stateChange.asObservable().pipe(
  debounceTime(500)
);


hubConnection.on("StateChanged", (state: string) => {
  this.stateChange .next(state); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is right solution, but anyway my application is still blocked with huge number of events which backend sends to the client service. Only separate thread could solve this problem. Or to reduce number of notifications on backend side.